# How can I use this PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I used to use the function below for an array or IP's but now I have changes the IP array from this:

```
$bannedIPs = array('127.0.0.0','72.189.218.85'); // Banned IPs array

ipban($bannedIPs);

function ipban($bannedIPs) {
    if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $bannedIPs)) { 
        include ("site_banip.php");
        session_destroy();
        exit;
    }   
}
```

to this:

```
$config_item['bannedIPs'] = array('127.0.0.0','72.189.218.85'); // Banned IPs array

ipban($config_item['bannedIPs']);

function ipban($bannedIPs) {
    if (in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $bannedIPs)) { 
        include ("site_banip.php");
        session_destroy();
        exit;
    }   
}
```

Now I cannot get it to work though,

```
Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in C:\webserver\htdocs\includes\functions.inc.php on line 948
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: Your comment is misspelled. ;)

Comment: yes, that is the actual code I am using above

Comment: Was that meant to be a reply to my answer? Are you sure you're updating the right page? It doesn't seem to be throwing an error for my local page.

Comment: Is your code exactly as shown here? Might the 'bannedIPs' array be overwritten somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the second argument to be $config_item['bannedIPs'] and pass the $config_item to the function.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're passing in an array in your *real* page?

Comment: Ahh I just changed a lot of code around to use different classes and turned out the particular page with that array var is not included, sorry and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this, it will be very flexible in the future if you need to add more IPs.

```
$whitelist = array(
    // ".*.32.255.255", // Sample
    // "63.76.53.255", // Sample
    // "46..*..*..*", // Sample
    // "46.32..*..*", // Sample
    // "46.32.255..*", // Sample
    // "46..**.255.255", // Sample
);

foreach($whitelist as $ip)
{
    if (ereg($ip, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
    {
        include ("site_banip.php");
        session_destroy();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not use the ereg*-functions (POSIX). As of PHP 5.3.0 this extension is deprecated - use the preg_*-functions instead (PCRE).